# I'm trying to write random numbers to a file and then make a list from lines in Python but list takes '\n' too

Tags: python, list

I'm using a function to create random numbers and writing them line by line in a file named `random.txt` using `\n` in a for loop using this block of code:

```
dosya.write(str(randomNumber))
dosya.write('\n')
```

I need to make a list from lines and then sort that list using a sort function. I can see my random numbers line by line in that file but when I use `readline()` function like:

```
List = open("random.txt").readlines()
print List
```

the output is:

```
['22\n', '16\n', '1\n',  '4\n', '4\n']
```

why am I seeing `\n` after my numbers? I tried printing only first or second element and it didn't show any extra thing. What is wrong with whole list? When I use sort function it takes `\n` as well.

Comment: `List = [i.strip() for i in open("random.txt").readlines()]`

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to do. Can you try formatting your code properly? Use lots of newlines and indent all the code with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.readlines()` methods reads each line including the line ending `\n` as a list element.
You likely want your random numbers as integers anyway.
Converting them to `int` would make your sorting work also:

```
with open("random.txt") as fobj:
    data = [int(line) for line in fobj]
```

The `with` opens the file with the promise to close it as soon as you leave the indentation. The open file object `fobj` is iterable. Therefore, you can write a list comprehension directly over `fobj` converting each line into an integer. It removes all newline characters `n` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each line and cast the line to an int and append to an array.

```
f=open('random.txt','r')

array = []
for line in f: # read  lines
    array.append(int(line))

f.closed
```